# Best way to take money from USA to Italy

Tags: banking, currency

I am in USA on temporary immigration status and I got an opportunity to move to Italy. I have saved up some money and I would like to use this money in Italy. There is a  chance that I might return to USA after 3 years.

I am not sure what the best way to transfer this money is.

I would like to close my USA bank accounts at some point in time as they are not free (Wells Fargo).

Should I convert my money into euros, store it in a currency card and take it to Italy?

I also have credit cards which I would like to cancel.

Should I take some money and then wire the money to myself from my US bank account to my Italian bank account and then close the US account?

The money I have is in the ballpark of 12000 usd

Answer (score 4):

It rather depends on how much money you have:

### $100

- Withdraw the money as Euro notes and close the account

### $1,000

- Transfer the money into a prepaid Euro account and close the account

### $10,100 to $100,000

- Take a small amount of cash or prepaid card with you (enough to last you until your Italian bank account is opened).
- In Italy, open an Italian bank account
- Transfer the balance of the money with something like Transferwise.
- Close the account when you are sure you don't need it any more

### $1,000,000

- Pay for professional advice

### In addition

Don't forget the currency transfer/import/export reporting requirements. The bank should take care of these for transfers, but if you leave the US with cash (in any denomination) or cash equivalents with a value of $10,000 or more, you have to report it. The same is true of entering the EU with cash and cash equivalents with a value of €10,000 or more. Structuring a transaction to avoid the requirement is a crime (in the US, at least), so don't carry an amount just under the threshold, and especially don't say that you chose the amount to avoid having to report.

Comment: Thanks! I am in your 10000-100000 range. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: @Morpheus don't forget the currency transfer/import/export reporting requirements.  The bank should take care of these for transfers, but if you leave the US with cash (in any denomination) or cash equivalents with a value of $10,000 or more, you have to report it.  The same is true of entering the EU with cash and cash equivalents with a value of €10,000 or more.  Structuring a transaction to avoid the requirement is a crime (in the US, at least), so don't carry an amount just under the threshold, and especially don't say that you chose the amount to avoid having to report.

Comment: @phoog - Good point.  I've added that comment into the answer.

Comment: @MartinBonner By cash do you mean bank notes or do you actually mean money in any form?

Comment: By cash I meant bank notes/coins.  What other sort of money is there?

Comment: Like putting the money in a currency exchange card.

Comment: @Morpheus I do not know whether a currency card is considered a cash equivalent, but I would not risk it.  A bank check endorsed to the bearer is a cash equivalent, for example. See https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/778/~/declaring-currency-when-entering-the-u.s.-in-transit-to-a-foreign-destination and (pdf) https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/currency_reporting.pdf.

Comment: Thanks! I am not a US citizen. I might never come back to USA. I will talk to my bank and seek their advise.

Comment: @MartinBonner could you add some more detail to what you mean by "Transfer the money into a prepaid Euro account"?

Comment: @MikeHarris I probably meant a prepaid forex card.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [TransferWise](https://TransferWise.com) to transfer funds between countries. It is the fastest method I have used, allows storage of multiple currencies in the account you create with them, and is widely recognized on expat sites as reliable.